# converting date and time string to unsigned __int64 in C++

Tags: c++

I have a requirement in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), which I have to read a file which consists date and time and convert it to `unsigned __int64`.

For example I have a file "mytime.txt" with following data.

```
2012-06-25 05:32:06.963
```

How do I convert it to `unsigned __int64`, and how do I convert back from `unsigned __int64` to the above string to write to file and also to verify it is converted to `unsigned __int64` correctly.

I am working on windows in VS.NET C++ compiler.

I am not supposed to use `boost`.

Comment: The standard C library doesn't handle resolutions under one second, so you have to resort to platform specific functions. As for parsing the string, use either one of the [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) functions, [regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex), or extract directly using something like [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404393/date-time-parsing-in-c-any-format-string-to-epoch) - yours is a subset of it.

Comment: @AleksG The poster says he is not supposed to use Boost, so the answer in that question is not applicable.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Oops, my bad: missed that line.

Comment: "atoi" would produce `2012`, which is a valid `__int64`. But presumably you wanted a different result. Which?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `strptime` to convert your string into struct and than use it to convert to time_t and do reverse using  `gmtime`

```
struct tm tm;
time_t epoch;
if ( strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm) != NULL )
  epoch = mktime(&tm);

// Reverse 
  struct tm * ptm;

  time ( &epoch );

  ptm = gmtime ( &epoch );
```